# VS 2010 scroll problems viewing .cs files C# code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scroll

For some reason when I scroll code from *.cs files VS2010 messed up different lines(symbols of code). When I select the row of code it(current row) shows correct, but all other lines are messed. It seems that VS don't refresh screen during scroll.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any add-ons installed? If so it may be that one of them is causing poor performance / rendering issues within VS when you try and scroll. Disable each one to see if the issue resolves itself.

Comment: After removing the same problem... Interesting thing is that during editing *.aspx or *.js files all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by reinstalled Windows 7 and VS 2010.